# How to set up a hourly cookie alert?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm looking for a cookie code that will remind people to enter a site once in a hour.

As I never worked with cookies till now, I have no idea how to set it up.
Does anyone knows how to set up a cookie code that will alert people on their screens to enter a site once in a hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a cookie, that is a notification.

Read more on those here: https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/